# Rails: Stack level too deep error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, searchlogic

My rails app has 3 models. Trail, Region and Feature. I am able to interact with these models fine in my lib/tasks directory. I used anemone to crawl and populate the database. Examples of calls I made on the models:

```
Trail.find_or_initialize_by_title(detail_title)
```

I am now trying to write a controller that uses the model.

```
class TrailController < ApplicationController
    def index
        render :json => Trail.all
    end
end
```

Now if i open rails console and try `app.get('trail/index')` I get a 500 return code and I see the following in my `development.log`

> SystemStackError (stack level too deep):
>   app/controllers/trail_controller.rb:23:in `index'

So I'm obviously causing some infinite recursion. Line 23 corresponds to the body of the index method. I've tried the other models in my app: Feature and Region and the result is the same. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here, or how I can get more tracing to figure out what exactly is recursing infinitely?

My models are very simple:

```
class Feature < ActiveRecord::Base 
  attr_accessible :name 
  has_and_belongs_to_many :trails 
  validates :name, :presence => true
end 

class Region < ActiveRecord::Base 
  attr_accessible :hash_key, :name 
  has_many :trails 
  validates :hash_key, :name, :presence => true 
end 

class Trail < ActiveRecord::Base 
  # attr_accessible :title, :body 
  has_and_belongs_to_many :features 
  validates :title, :presence => true    
end
```

It appears this is somehow being caused by the searchlogic gem. I have this in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'rd_searchlogic', :require => 'searchlogic', :git => 'git://github.com/railsdog/searchlogic.|~
```

When i comment out that line, run bundle install and retry app.get things work fine. So searchlogic is somehow interfering with Trail.all. Why won't Trail.all work with searchlogic installed?

Comment: What happens if you do : `trails = Trail.all; render json: trails` ?

Comment: I guess you overwrote as_json or to_json in one of these models.

Comment: I tried `trails = Trail.all; render :json => trails` and got the same error.

Comment: I dont think so since the models are very simple. Here is all their code: `class Feature < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_and_belongs_to_many :trails
  validates :name, :presence=>true
end
class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :hash_key, :name
  has_many :trails
  validates :hash_key, :name, :presence=>true
end
class Trail < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
  has_and_belongs_to_many :features
  validates :title, :presence=>true
end`

Comment: This link [http://kiranb.scripts.mit.edu/blog/?p=247](http://kiranb.scripts.mit.edu/blog/?p=247) appears to indicate searchlogic wont play nice with Rails 3.2.8, which is what i'm running.  I'm looking at [squeel](http://railscasts.com/episodes/354-squeel) as an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

The rd_searchlogic gem was the source of the issue. http://kiranb.scripts.mit.edu/blog/?p=247 talks about the issue. "Any named scope Searchlogic creates is dynamic and created via method_missing. And because Rails 3.1 changed around activerecord so much, Searchlogic calls a missing method on activerecord, which then gets rerouted to searchlogic."

I decided to switch to meta_where, only to learn that it's not supported from Rails 3.1 onwards. I'm running Rails 3.2.8. Squeel is the replacement, and works great on Rails 3.2.8: https://github.com/ernie/squeel